# why i am not able to move from loginpage in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I have Registration, Login and Home viewcontrollers

my app flow is **1) if i register with name password then i need to go home page and in home page if i tap logout i need to go login page
2) after registration if i go login with registration name and password i need to go home page and if i logout then move to home page**

```
 navigationcontroller(is initial viewcontroller) -> loginpage (login button or registration button) -> homepage
```

in scenedelegate:

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
  
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == true{
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc_Home = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        window!.rootViewController = vc_Home
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }else{
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc_Home = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        window!.rootViewController = vc_Home
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

in my login viewcontroller:

```
@IBAction func loginBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let uName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
    
    let uPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userPassword")

    if userNameTextfield.text == uName && passwordTextfield.text == uPassword{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        showAlert(title: "LogIn", message: "please enter username and password")

    }
}

@IBAction func registerBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterViewController") as! RegisterViewController
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

in registration page code:

```
@IBAction func registerBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if firstNameTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter first name")

    }
    else if lastNameTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter last name")

    }else if emailTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter email")

    }else if passwordTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter password")

    }
    else{
        
        let fName = firstNameTextfield.text!
        let lName = lastNameTextfield.text!
        let userNameReg =  fName + " " + lName
        
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userNameReg, forKey: "userName")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(lastNameTextfield.text, forKey: "lastName")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(emailTextfield.text, forKey: "email")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(passwordTextfield.text, forKey: "userPassword")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
        }
      }
```

in home page:

```
 @IBAction func logoutBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
  
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

here i am unable to move from loginpage if i hit loginBtn or registrationBtn i am unable to move why?

please do help with code

Comment: Does your login view controller have UINavigationController?

Comment: @RajaKishan yes loginvc has UINavigationController and its the initialVC

Comment: Try to add breakpoints and check

Comment: @RajaKishan what should i check.. i am not moving from loginVC.. where am i wrong pls do help with code

Comment: @RajaKishan or guide me to login register and logout flow

Comment: @RajaKishan this is total code can u answer here